# Maximum/Minimum Object

Tags: c#, double, .net-4.5, point

In C#, is there a build-in-class that is intended for storing minimum and maximum values as doubles?

The Point listed here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.point.point(v=vs.110).aspx would word perfectly, except I cannot create this Point.  I don't think it is supported with what I am doing.  I just get the Point(int, int), the `System.Drawing` one.  It is not letting add using `System.Window`.

So for storing 2 doubles, what do you recommend?  Create my own class, actually use 2 doubles (ugh), or is there some other Object I can use?

Comment: what's wrong with creating a class (or better a struct) for this?

Comment: Nothing at all. I was just curious if there was already something out there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would create a custom class and name it something related to the meaning of the two doubles

Comment: Ended up using this class cuz of static issues with tuple. checkmark. thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The `Point` class is actually `System.Windows.Point` not `System.Window.Point`. Is that your problem?

Failing that, you could use a [`Tuple`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - this generic class holds two values of any type. So `Tuple<double, double>` would give you two doubles, accessed as `thing.Item1` and `thing.Item2`

But seriously, if you want to store a minimum and maximum, you should really create a class with two double values named `Minimum` and `Maximum`. Don't go using some unrelated type like `Point` just to save a couple of lines of typing.